# How would I rewrite this javascript command in playwright? document.getElementsByClassName(parent)[i].querySelector(child)

Tags: javascript, playwright

I have this command in javascript that works, but can't seem to translate it into playwright. For my project, I have 10 item cards and I need to find if item description is missing inside each item card or not. (there should be 1 missing description in my case)

`document.getElementsByClassName(itemCard)[i].querySelector(itemDescription)`

I've tried

```
const rows = await this.page.locator(itemCard); 
 inside loop)
 if (await rows.locator('has:itemDescription').nth(i) == null) { 
        console.log("No description") } 
 else { console.log("has description"}
```

but the above code seems to print out 10 "has descriptions" instead of 9. There should be one "No description".

Comment: Can you show the markup? This feels a little too pseudocodey to offer a proper answer. There's probably a cleaner way than your original approach. It's unusual to have to use `[i]` in querying the DOM. Something like `[...document.querySelectorAll(".card")].filter(e => e.querySelector(".description")).length === 10` or something. Also `(await rows.locator('has:itemDescription').nth(i) == null)` should be `((await rows.locator('has:itemDescription').nth(i)) == null)` so the promise resolves first, then the null is compared against the resolved value.

Comment: the original line was just from the console debugger. I made sure that "document.getElementsByClassName(itemCard)[4].querySelector(itemDescription)" returned the description, but if it's index 5, returned null.

Also, adding the latter () to the await didn't make a difference. =(

Comment: The problem with my if statement from above is that it skips the item card that has no description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do an almost exact translation of what you seemed to be doing, your if condition could translate to this:

```js
if (!(await rows.nth(i).locator(itemDescription).isVisible())) {
```

I don’t know the full context/goal or what your actual core requirement is, but if it satisfies it, you could also just get a count of how many exist, and assert or log how many there are. To get this count, you could do something like this:

```js
await rows.filter({ has: this.page.locator(itemDescription) }).count();
```

Also just realized that you were doing get by class name before, so your rows locator also would need a tweak to specify css class, like so:

```js
const rows = await this.page.locator(`.${itemCard}`);
```

Happy to provide more specifics if needed and given more context. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much David! That did the trick, I was able to get what I needed from it. Much appreciated!!